# Debian 11: no root access anymore

Tags: debian, sudo, su

After trying to reinstall my amd-gpu-drivers, my system rebooted into CLI. So I tried to reinstall GUI with "apt install task-gnome-desktop". After this my system says sudo is an unknown command. Tried with su- but system says "Authentication failure", possibly because root was never set. So I think I lost root access.
Is it possible "task-gnome-desktop" removed sudo and locked me out?

How can I set root password?

Any hint very welcome.

Comment: Check your $PATH?

Comment: $PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you able to boot into single user mode?

Comment: Managed to successfully set a root password (via Grub) and reinstalled sudo. Problem solved. Thanks for comments.